# Check Spark packages version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to set up my first `Scala` project with `IntelliJ Idea` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. I need the `Spark` library and I think I have installed correctly in my computer, however I am not able to refer it in the project dependencies. In particular, I have added the following code in my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql" % "2.1.1")
```

However `sbt` complains about not finding the correct packages (`Unresolved Dependencies` error, `org.apache.spark#spark-core;2.1.1: not found` and `org.apache.spark#spark-sql;2.1.1: not found`):

I think that the versions of the packages are incorrect (I copied the previous code from the web, just to try).

How can I determine the correct packages versions?

Comment: @AreTour, you need to bind  **scala version** with your dependency,  In **SBT**, you can do it by `%%`: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `%` you have to define the exact version as

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.1.1")
```

And if you don't want to define the version and let `sbt` take the correct version then you need to define `%%` as

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1")
```

you can check of installed version by doing

```
spark-submit --version
```

And by going to [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark)

Comment: Ok, that solves partially my problem, since I want to know the exact version. Where can I find this information?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope if thats what you are looking for

Comment: `sbt` was taking an incorrect version so I manually added it.
After some test, with the help of your resources I figured out my version.

Comment: great to hear that the answer helped :)